# Can I use my iPhone as a hotspot on Wifi (instead of 3G/4G)?

Tags: iphone, wifi, cellular-data

I would like to use my jailbroken iPhone as a hotspot for my MacBook. It works well when my 3G internet is enabled. But when I disable it, the hotspot menu becomes unavailable... even if my iPhone is connected on the WiFi network.

I disabled the 3G to make sure it wouldn't use my 3G data plan.

Can I use my iPhone as a hotspot on WiFi (instead of 3G)?

Comment: Another reason why needed: Some networks are very secure and require Mac address to be added first. If you need WiFi temporarily on a separate device than which is already on it, you can tether it as mentioned, than trying to get WiFi permissions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with USB or Bluetooth tethering on jailbroken iOS devices using an app such as [MyWi](http://intelliborn.com/mywi.html).  There are many other jailbreak apps for this function, so it's worth shopping around.

Some will only share the 3G internet connection, but I understand others will share any internet connection over USB or bluetooth.

You can't use wifi tethering to connect your computer to a wifi network your phone knows about.

The hotspot creates a new wireless network, but the iPhone is capable of attaching to only one wireless network at a time.  It cannot connect to a wireless network with internet and create its own wireless network to share.

Since the iPhone is on the wireless network, though, you can get your computer on that same network since it will likely be in range.

Comment: You are assuming the second computer has a wireless card... which is not the case.  Otherwise, I would connect directly!

Comment: @Maxime Ah, I see what you're saying.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: 2020 update: MyWi doesn't work past iOS 9, but [Tetherme](https://www.tetherme.net/) seems to based on what I've read

Answer (score 6):

According to an [Apple Support KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4517):

> You cannot use your Wi-Fi connection for Internet connectivity while
>   other devices are using Wi-Fi for Personal Hotspot. **You can share only
>   a cellular data connection; you cannot share a Wi-Fi connection.**

[This KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3574) mentions the support for hotspots, by device:

[image: iOS hotspot chart]

While this Apple Support information might not apply to jail-broken devices, it's good for reference.

Comment: A phone (certainly Android phones) can serve as an access point using its wifi radio. Connected devices can communicate with the internet or with each other (e.g. pulling down the phone’s camera stream) and I see absolutely no reason why this is not a valid use case. Granted, power users are likely the only ones to understand networking - but it is odd that Apple requires the cellular data in order to broadcast local machine to machine traffic across its own network when serving as an access point. FAIL.