# iPhone 4s Wi-Fi hotspot app through Wi-Fi, not 3G

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, iphone, tethering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my iPhone as a hotspot on Wifi (instead of 3G)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46209/can-i-use-my-iphone-as-a-hotspot-on-wifi-instead-of-3g)

I have an iPhone 4s that I want to turn into a Wi-Fi hotspot. I don't want to use the 3G connection to do this. I want to use the Wi-Fi coming into the phone as the source. How can I do this without jailbreaking? Anyone know of an app. It can be free or paid.

Comment: I am pretty certain an iphone cannot work as a repeater.  You'd be better off connecting the wifi device direct to the AP the 4s is talking to.

Comment: You have to have two network cards to become a repeater, and that's that. That's something that not even JailBreaking can fix.

Comment: Hi @Paul, please rewrite your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer